# Compiler errors when consuming NuGet packages from an F# library targeting .NET Core

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, nuget, .net-core

I am having some trouble opening namespaces in certain NuGet packages (e.g. Newtonsoft.Json and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) when targeting .NET Core from an F# library project.

Here are the steps leading up to my issue:

1. Installed "Visual Studio 2015 Update 3" and ".NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2" from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows
2. Created an empty solution with the following contents:

   ```
   Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00  
   # Visual Studio 14
   VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1  
   MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1  
   Global  
       GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution  
           HideSolutionNode = FALSE  
       EndGlobalSection  
   EndGlobal
   ```
3. Created an empty project directory in the solution directory
4. Within the empty project directory, ran the command:

   ```
   dotnet new -t lib --lang f#
   ```

   which created a Library.fs file:

   ```
   namespace Library

   module Say =
       let hello name =
           printfn "Hello %s" name
   ```

   and a project.json file:

   ```
   {
     "version": "1.0.0-*",
     "buildOptions": {
       "debugType": "portable",
       "compilerName": "fsc",
       "compile": {
         "includeFiles": [
           "Library.fs"
         ]
       }
     },
     "tools": {
       "dotnet-compile-fsc":"1.0.0-preview2-*"
     },
     "frameworks": {
       "netstandard1.6": {
         "dependencies": {
           "NETStandard.Library":"1.6.0",
           "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore": "1.0.0-alpha-160629"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. Added this existing project to my solution, and package restore worked fine
6. NuGet Package Manager UI failed to open, however, because

   ```
   "dotnet-compile-fsc":"1.0.0-preview2-*"
   ```

   from the project.json file was "not a valid version string"
7. Ran the command

   ```
   dotnet -version
   ```

   and replaced the "invalid version" with actual version "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
8. NuGet Package Manager UI then opened correctly and displayed the following installed packages:

   - dotnet-compile-fsc v1.0.0-preview2-003131
   - Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore v1.0.0-alpha-160629
   - NETStandard.Library v1.6.0
9. Installed the package Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.1 which added the following to the root of the project.json file:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
   }
   ```
10. Added the following lines to the Library.fs file:

    ```
    open System
    open Newtonsoft.Json
    ```

    but the compiler gives me the error "The namespace or module 'Newtonsoft' is not defined"
11. Created a new Visual C# .NET Core Class Library project in the same solution using the template in Visual Studio 2015 which created a Class1.cs file:

    ```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace example2
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            public Class1()
            {
            }
        }
    }
    ```

    and a project.json file:

    ```
    {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",

      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
          "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
      }
    }
    ```
12. Installed the package Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.1 to the C# project which updated the dependencies in the project.json file:

    ```
    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
    }
    ```
13. Added the following line to the Class1.cs file:

    ```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    ```

    and there were no compiler issues

---

I have the same issue with the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer NuGet package.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing incorrectly in the F# project that prevents me from using these packages?

Comment: Did you try adding ` "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0" ` to  dependencies section of project.json in F# project.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and other tweaks to make it look more like the C# project.json, but I could not find a working combination.

Comment: How did you add the F# library to an existing solution? As far as I know the .NET CLI command `dotnet new -t lib --lang f#` doesn't create an `.fsproj` file or anything else that could be added to a solution in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @dustinmoris, I've already explained that in the question itself. The whole point of that CLI command is to create a project file (in this case: project.json) so I'm not sure where you got your information.

Comment: Your issue is very confusing. You are mixing a lot of terms which have double meanings and it is not clear what you exactly do. > "5) Added this existing project to my solution, and package restore worked fine" What existing project? The newly created F# project? How can you add a project.json to a .sln file? I thought you must have a csproj or fsproj in order to add a project to a solution or perhaps you mean by solution something different that what a .NET solution is (.sln)

Comment: @dustinmoris, yes, if you create a project with the CLI, then it would be an existing project when you add it to a solution in Visual Studio. Yes, you can add a project.json to a Visual Studio solution in the same way as .csproj or .fsproj. Seems like you could have easily tested that for yourself instead of assuming that it was not possible.

Comment: Seeing that you can add a file somewhere, is not the same as it being magically consumed for a purpose elsewhere.

Comment: There's nothing "magic" about the documented functionality of the `dotnet` command line tool. It works exactly as documented for the case in question. Dustin was neither reading the info in the question nor was he informed about the tool for which he was making claims.